# Read a table with missing data

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to read a table with missing data -- using the columns-based labels? I have the following table:

```
                      Band                             Band                %  of
  Band   Peak         for                          %   for  Area           Total
   No.   Pos.   Delta Sep.  Separ.  Height  FWHM Gauss Area Ratio   Area   Area 
    4   214.01   4.67   3     2.70    5737  1.69   90    3   0.67   10836  30.76
    2   212.04   2.70   1     2.70    1391  2.10   90    1   0.67    3254   9.24
    3   211.31   1.97   0             8580  1.70   90    0          16255  46.14
    1   209.34   0.00   0             2193  2.00   90    0           4882  13.86
```

I want to read it in a column-based way. I believe `pandas` can do it. I'd skip first two rows -- but how do I make `pandas` read the remaining data in a column-based way?

Any other solution to parse such tables (with missing data) would also be ok.

Comment: I'm about to be caught in transit, but you can use `read_fwf` in a recent version of pandas.

Comment: Please make it an answer: `pandas.read_fwf("1.txt", widths=[6,  8,  7,  5,  8,  8,  6,  6,  5,  6,  8,  7], skiprows=3)` works.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I managed to do it with:

```
asciitable.read("1.txt", Reader=asciitable.FixedWidthNoHeader,
                col_starts=( 8, 16, 22, 28, 36, 44, 49, 55, 60, 67, 74),
                col_ends  =(14, 21, 25, 34, 42, 48, 53, 58, 65, 73, 80))
```

discarding first three rows.

**Edit**:

As [DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) notes -- same can be acheived with `pandas`:

```
pandas.read_fwf("1.txt", widths=[6, 8, 7, 5, 8, 8, 6, 6, 5, 6, 8, 7], skiprows=3)
```

Comment: `pandas` version works perfect, `widths` parameter is optional so skipping that makes `pandas` calculate it on its own. awesome!

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_table('example.txt', skiprows=3, sep=r'\s*' )
```

if theres only spaces in the middle I don't think its going to work but its hard to say without sample data.

Comment: You have the sample data -- I cite the representative data in the question. I tried You example it doesn't work: it can't take into account that some values are missing.

Comment: I guess I was wondering if there were any non-space characters in the empty spaces - like a tab. But I suppose if there were `read_table()` would parse it just fine.